# Scaling cairo context on draw call from gtk window takes too long

Tags: c, gtk, cairo

I've been working on gtk+/cairo application where I need to display an image on a drawing area and draw some text and lines on top of it. I already made the functions that draw all the necessary graphics into the cairo context, but the image needs to be scaled in order to fit into the drawing area (and also to avoid scaling issues when changing the window's size).I planned on doing this by just using the cairo_scale function, but this option seems to be rather slow.

Here's how I'm currently scaling the cairo context:

```
***
typedef struct diagram_properties_{
    cairo_surface_t * surface;
    d_tank_ tanks[DIAGRAM_TANK_COUNT];
    d_valve_ valves[DIAGRAM_VALVE_COUNT];
    d_info_ infos[DIAGRAM_INFO_COUNT];
    int last_error_;
    double width, height;
    bool is_saved;
    GtkDrawingArea * drawing_area;
}diagram_properties_;
***
gboolean on_draw_diagram_event(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer user_data){
    //Initialize diagram (d_properties)
    draw_diagram(cr, &d_properties);
    return FALSE;
}
***
void draw_diagram( cairo_t *cr, diagram_properties_ *diagram ){

    GtkWidget * da_widget = GTK_WIDGET(diagram->drawing_area);
    gtk_widget_queue_draw(da_widget);
    GtkAllocation allocation;
    gtk_widget_get_allocation(da_widget, &allocation);
    diagram->width = cairo_image_surface_get_width(diagram->surface);
    diagram->height = cairo_image_surface_get_height(diagram->surface);
    cairo_scale(cr, allocation.width / diagram->width, allocation.height /     diagram->height);
    cairo_set_source_surface(cr, diagram->surface, 0, 0);
    cairo_paint(cr);
    update_diagram_tanks( cr, diagram );
    update_diagram_valves( cr, diagram );
    update_diagram_info( cr, diagram );
}
***
```

The PNG file with the diagram is used to create the diagram surface at the beginning of the code. So my question is, is there a way to save the cairo context on a buffer and only scale it whenever the window's dimensions change? I'm already trying to scale the surfaces themselves instead, as well as the coordinates of the drawings and text, but I'd rather avoid doing so if there's a better way to do it available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a combination of `cairo_push_group()`, `cairo_get_group_target()` and `cairo_pop_group_to_source()`+`cairo_paint()` to draw your scaled content.

Pseudo-Code:

```
static cairo_surface_t *cache_surface = NULL;
static double cache_width = -1, cache_height = -1;

// s must be an image surface and it must always be the same image surface (= content must not change)
void draw_at_size(cairo_t *cr, cairo_surface_t *s, double width, double height)
{
  double diagram_width = cairo_image_surface_get_width(s);
  double diagram_height = cairo_image_surface_get_height(s);
  cairo_set_operator(cr, CAIRO_OPERATOR_SOURCE);
  if (width == cache_width && height == cache_height) {
    cairo_set_source_surface(cr, cache_surface, 0, 0);
    cairo_paint(cr);
  } else {
    cairo_push_group(cr);
    cairo_scale(cr, width / diagram_width, height / diagram_height);
    cairo_set_source_surface(cr, surface, 0, 0);
    cairo_paint(cr);

    cairo_surface_destroy(cache_surface);
    cache_surface = cairo_reference(cairo_get_group_target(cr));
    cache_width = width;
    cache_height = height;

    cairo_pop_group_to_source(cr);
    cairo_paint(cr);
  }
}
```

No idea if this is really faster, but it means that the surface is only scaled once. Of course you can also extend this by drawing other stuff onto the scaled surface.

However, that is basically the same as allocating another surface yourself. The only difference is that the surface allocation is hidden and that you might get a "better" surface, e.g. I guess you are currently allocating an image surface for the temporary surface, but cairo would use an X11 surface on X11.

Comment: I think I know what you're trying to do (I should have mentioned I only have like 3 days of experience with cairo), but when I try to do that I get an
```Assertion `CAIRO_REFERENCE_COUNT_HAS_REFERENCE (&cr->ref_count)' failed.``` error (I changed the line ```cache_surface = cairo_reference(cairo_get_group_target(cr));``` to ```cache_surface = cairo_get_target(cairo_reference(cairo_get_group_target(cr)));```, tried again and it also didn't work), but I'll be looking into ```cairo_push_group(), cairo_get_group_target()``` later today. I'll be posting an update (hopefully) tomorrow. Thanks btw!

Comment: Whoops, sorry. It should be `cairo_surface_reference` instead of `cairo_reference`. Your compiler should warn about a cast from `cairo_surface_t*` to `cairo_t*`. That warning is a serious problem here and causes the crash.

Comment: So the line should be `cairo_surface_reference(cairo_get_group_target(cr))`.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply Uli!, I just included the drawing call on a function that is executed by an g_timeout_add call 10 times a second, and it works good enough for this application. However, I'll be trying your solution on the next version of the app if you don't mind, so thank you for your help, and sorry I didn't got the chance to try it out before

Comment: Now that I see this code again: This might leak surfaces. `cache_surface` should be unreferenced before it is overwritten (and yes, `cairo_surface_destroy(NULL)` is safe).